# Javascript: Why don't array methods return a new array?

Tags: javascript, immutability, mutable, primitive-types, mutability

I understand that the reason methods on strings return a new string is that strings are immutable, so the method can't modify the string you pass to it.

With an array, if you pass it to a method, that method *can* modify the array because arrays are mutable. I'm wondering why array methods (and methods on other mutable types) aren't written to return a new array, such that they would be consistent with the methods on primitive types like strings.

For example, `arr.map()` might be written like this:

```
function map = (arr) => {
  ...<logic>...
}
```

where it could be written like this:

```
function map = (arr) => {
  let arr_ = arr.slice()
  ...<logic>...
  return arr_
}
```

Is there a reason methods on mutable types aren't written in this way?

Comment: It depends on the function. For example, `.map()` returns a new array while `.sort` modifies the array in place. A lot of the reason why is due to what makes sense for the context.

Comment: https://doesitmutate.xyz/

Comment: It would mean creating an extra *copy* of a potentially large data structure